evenSum method takes too long to execute in edge cases, how can I optimize the loop?
I am working on a Java method called evenSum that sums all even numbers between two integers, from and to, inclusive. The requirements specify that if from is greater than to, the method should return -1. For example, evenSum(4, 6) should return 10, evenSum(10, 15) should return 36, and evenSum(4, 4) should return 4.
Although the method works for many cases, it fails test 8 due to performance issues, taking too long to execute. The test output suggests that the loop conditions might be inefficient.
The method currently checks if from is odd and increments it to the next even number, then sums even numbers in a loop until it reaches to. I suspect the loop is not optimized, especially for larger ranges.
I would appreciate any suggestions for improving the efficiency of my code to prevent timing out during tests. Initially, I expected the method to calculate the sum correctly for various input ranges, including edge cases. While it passed the first seven tests, it failed test 8 unexpectedly, leading me to believe there may be an inefficiency in the loop.
My code:
public static long evenSum(int from, int to) {
    if (from > to) {
        return -1L;
    }

    if (from % 2 != 0) {
        from++;
    }

    long sum = 0L;
    int currentValue = from;

    while (currentValue <= to) {
        sum += currentValue;
        currentValue += 2; 
    }

    return sum;
}


Are you allowed to "cheat", by just calculating the sum directly instead of iterating many times through a loop?

I think there are some nice mathematical properties that would allow you to simply calculate this, instead of brute-forcing it.

Do you even need a loop? This sounds like a mathematical problem, not a programmatic one (cf. https://www.cuemath.com/numbers/natural-numbers-from-1-to-100/). Adapting it to even numbers between a lower and upper bound yields a formula such as max*(max+1)/2 - min*(min-1)/2 (cast to long before calculating to avoid integer overflow)

@knittl That expression isn't correct; we need the sum of all even integers in a range, not all integers. This is simply an arithmetic series.

@Unmitigated oops, you are absolutely correct. The expression has the division in the wrong place. The correct expression is max/2*(max/2+1) - min/2*(min/2-1). Truncating the numbers makes it even work for odd inputs like in OP's example
